# Use of generic type parameter <T> when defining lambda expression

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

Consider the following snippet:

```
public class JavaApplication4 {

    static <T> List<T> functionConcat(List<T> l1, List<T> l2) {
        return Stream.concat(l1.stream(), l2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    // functionConcat in lambda form
    static final BinaryOperator<List<? extends Number>> lambdaConcat = (l1, l2)
            -> Stream.concat(l1.stream(), l2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // DOES NOT WORK with lambdaConcat
        final List<Integer> x = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>()
                .stream().reduce(new LinkedList<>(), lambdaConcat);
        final List<Double> y = new LinkedList<List<Double>>()
                .stream().reduce(new LinkedList<>(), lambdaConcat);

        // WORKS with functionConcat
        final List<Integer> x2 = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>()
                .stream().reduce(new LinkedList<>(), JavaApplication4::functionConcat);
        final List<Double> y2 = new LinkedList<List<Double>>()
                .stream().reduce(new LinkedList<>(), JavaApplication4::functionConcat);
    }

}
```

Is there a way to fix `lambdaConcat` such that the two corresponding statements in `main()` become correct?

I tried expressing the type as `BinaryOperator<List<Number>>`, `BinaryOperator<List<?>>`, `BinaryOperator<List<? extends Number>>`, and even `BinaryOperator<List>`, but, understandably, none of them work. Ideally, I would like to write `lambdaConcat` with a type parameter `<T>` as I did in `functionConcat`, but I haven't found a way to express that with a lambda expression.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This doesn't work because the `reduce()` operation's `BinaryOperator<T>` is invariant:

```
T reduce(T identity, BinaryOperator<T> accumulator);
```

This essentially means that if you pass a `List<Integer>` type as the identity, you also have to pass a `BinaryOperator<List<Integer>>` as the accumulator, not a `BinaryOperator<List<? extends Number>>`.

When using method references, or when inlining the lambda expression twice, you won't run into this issue, because `<T>` can be correctly inferred to `List<Integer>` each time. The problem is that you prevent this sort of type inference by assigning your lambda to a fixed type. If, instead, you wrote a higher order generic function that returned the lambda, it would work again:

```
static final <T extends Number> BinaryOperator<List<T>> lambdaConcat() {
    return (l1, l2)->Stream.concat(l1.stream(), l2.stream()).collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

You can now write:

```
final List<Integer> x = new LinkedList<List<Integer>>()
        .stream().reduce(new LinkedList<>(), lambdaConcat());
final List<Double> y = new LinkedList<List<Double>>()
        .stream().reduce(new LinkedList<>(), lambdaConcat());
```

Of course, at this point, the method reference solution is probably still better.

Comment: Not to disagree with your ultimate conclusion, but `BinaryOperator<T>` has to be invariant since `T` is used for both inputs and outputs. And, for the output, `? extends Number` isn't precise enough. We need `T` to be `Integer` or `Double` as you've shown. Note that the original `lambdaConcat` seems to be an attempt at rank-2 polymorphism!

Comment: @JohnVasileff, Indeed: `BinaryOperator` has to be invariant